# Unable to start neo4j service on Linux

Tags: java, linux, service, neo4j

We followed the steps to install neo4j and create service from [installation link](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Installing_Neo4j_in_Linux)

We were able to create the service on our linux machine but its giving the following Error of Java path.

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# service neo4j-service status
which: no java in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin)
ERROR: Unable to find java. (Cannot execute )
* Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see http://docs.neo4j.org/ for Neo4j Server installation instructions.[root@localhost Desktop]#
```

**On echo $JAVA_HOME = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java**

**On echo $PATH=
/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin:/usr/local/apache2/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin**

Where is the problem in starting the service?

Comment: In my case it was really simple... I simply needed to use "sudo" >_> \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java /usr/bin
```